# Passing object of another class into constructor of current class C++ (Not member initialization)

Tags: c++

I am trying to pass an object of `Pair` class into the constructor of the `FollowsQuery` class as shown below. I am getting a `no default constructor exists` error. I am not sure how to rectify this error.

This is the definition of the `Pair` class below in **Pair.h**. The object is created via a static method `CreatePair`.

```
class Pair
{
public:
    pair<DesignEntities, string> firstPair;
    pair<DesignEntities, string> secondPair;

    static Pair CreatePair(string first, string second, map<string, DesignEntities> varMap);
    pair<int, int> getStatementAndPos();
    pair<DesignEntities, DesignEntities> getTypes();

private:
    Pair(pair<DesignEntities, string> first, pair<DesignEntities, string> second);

};
```

This is my follows query class definition file. **FollowsQuery.h**

```
class FollowsQuery : Query {
public:
    FollowsQuery(Pair pair);
    ~FollowsQuery();
    Pair pair; // for (s1,s2) in follows(s1,s2)
    list<int> filterList;


    void setList(list<int> filteredList); // set the curr list from the prev select
    list<string> evaluate(PKB pkb);
    bool isRelatedToSelect(DesignEntities designEntity); // check if design entity was from prev select
};
```

This is my **FollowsQuery.c** class file, where the error occurs.

```
FollowsQuery::FollowsQuery(Pair pair) {
this->pair = pair;
}
```

Even though I have looked through stackoverflow and found similar questions, I have been unable to find the answer because I want to create the `Pair` class separately and pass it into the constructor of `FollowsQuery`.

Comment: You use `Pair` correctly in the definition (implementation) of the `FollowsQuery` constructor, but not in the declaration of the constructor. What are the differences between the two?

Comment: I have tried this constructor but i dont get it still.


FollowsQuery::FollowsQuery(Pair pair(std::pair<DesignEntities, string>, std::pair<DesignEntities, string>)) {
 this->pair = pair;
}

Comment: I said that the *definition* (the implementation) used it correctly, you should copy that way into the declaration in the class instead of the opposite. `Pair pair` is the correct way to declare a variable (including arguments). All your other functions declare their arguments correctly, it's only the declaration of the `FollowsQuery` constructor that you do it wrong. I don't want to insult you, but perhaps you should take some time to refresh some basic C++?

Comment: I have changed the declaration in the header file to FollowsQuery(Pair pair), but the .cpp file is still telling me that no default constructor exists.

Comment: Oh, that's a different error. When asking questions about build error, please always include the ***full*** and ***complete*** error output in the question, copy-pasted as text. It's kind of hard to see what error you're asking about, especially since the `FollowsQuery` constructor declaration stood out with its error.

Comment: Yes. I was jus trying out different ways to see which could solve the issue..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the "no default constructor exist" for the `pair` member of the `FollowsQuery` class, because the compiler tries to default-construct `pair` but the `Pair` class doesn't have a default constructor.

What happens in the `FollowsQuery` construction is basically this:

```
FollowsQuery::FollowsQuery(Pair pair)
    // Here the `FollowsQuery::pair` member is default constructed
{
    // Here you assign to the already constructed `FollowsQuery::pair` member
    this->pair = pair;
}
```

As the `Pair` class doesn't have a default constructor (as mentioned) then this will not work.

You solve this by using a *constructor initializer list* to initialize (construct) the member variables:

```
FollowsQuery::FollowsQuery(Pair pair)
    : pair(pair)  // Copy-construct the `FollowsQuery::pair` member
{
    // Nothing needed here, the `FollowsQuery::pair` member is already initialized
}
```